# How to get write access to Android device over USB and mtp?

Tags: usb, permissions, kde, mtp

If I connect my smartphone over USB to my system, I can access it over the built in functionality with mtp:

KDE mtp dialog:

[image: KDE mtp dialog]

The device is mounted:

[image: Dolphin shows mount]

but files are read-only.

PDF file in Dolphin:

[image: PDF file in Dolphin]

Sure, I could use instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
pkill -x kiod5
sleep 2
jmtpfs /home/sd/Handy
dolphin ./Handy --new-window
```

but the file transfer is slow and stops sometimes, if some background tasks are doing something on the device, like creating thumbnails, getting media info, and more, which I don't know.

Is there a possibility to make the "standard" system mtp access to allow write access?

My system:

- OSy: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
- KDE Plasma version: 5.24.7
- KDE Frameworks version: 5.92.0
- Qt version: 5.15.3
- Kernel version: 5.15.0-70-lowlatency (64-bit)
- Graphics platform: X11
- Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel Core i7-13700K
- Memory: 62.6 GB RAM
- Graphics processor: llvmpipe

Comment: Seriously, this is a perfectly legitimate question. DO NOT just downvote without commenting!